# How To Save JSON text from Bing Using perl

Tags: json, perl

Hi i am new with perl i have a problem to save text from BING json

here

```
 use strict;
 use warnings;
 use LWP::UserAgent;
 my $uagent = LWP::UserAgent->new;
 my $bing = $uagent->get("http://api.bing.com/osjson.aspx?query=microsoft")->content;
 print "$bing\n";
```

i want to save to text file line by line only a

- microsoft
- microsoft security essentials
- microsoft update
- microsoft office
- microsoft downloads
- microsoft word
- microsoft templates
- microsoft updates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSON module can be used to parse the data into a Perl structure and then print out the required array elements. Add this code to the bottom of your script.

```
use JSON;
my $data = decode_json($bing);
print join ',', @{ $data->[1] };
```

Comment: Owh i forgot to mention i want an output write line by line the how to format the output

Answer (score 0):

First you want to install the JSON module from CPAN. You can do this by typing the following on the command line (assuming linux)

```
$ cpan JSON
```

Then you want to decode the JSON string into an object using the decode function

```
my $json = JSON->decode($bing);
```

I'm not really sure what you wanted to do from here but to save data to a text file you must first open a file handle

```
open my $FH, '>', 'filename.txt' or die "Failed to open file: $!";
```

Then to write a message to it you simply print to the filehandle you just opened ($FH)

```
print $FH 'This will be in filename.txt';
```

**Note: ** There is no comma between the $FH and the value being written to the file

Hope that helps